# How to commit an upgrade? When does it happen?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

So suppose I have upgraded all the hosts that are part of a cluster. Now I need to upgrade the security Database. Is this the part which commit the upgrade? What does commit an upgrade means? Does it mean upgrading security DB and checking the effective version of the cluster that it has switched to newer version or not? Or committing an upgrade is a different procedure altogether?

Also, Is it possible that the software version at one of the host didn't upgraded and we went ahead to upgrade the security DB and configurations. Will the effective version of the cluster will still switch to newer version?

Comment: Where did you come across the phrase 'committing an upgrade'?

Comment: http://docs.marklogic.com/admin:can-commit-upgrade

Comment: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/rolling-upgrades#id_90410

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Committing the upgrade happens after every node in the cluster has been upgraded. In the Admin GUI, when you see the security upgrade finish, this has happened. Until this happens and the new effective version is written to the `clusters.xml` configuration file, the cluster operates in a downgraded mode.